# How do i download MySql On Debian Based?

Tags: mysql, debian

I wanna make a db and i need mysql for that.

I was trying to do this command:
`sudo apt install mysql-server` and i got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian changed to "mariadb" due to license issues.

Ether use the `mariadb-server` package or the `default-mysql-server`, which depends on a mysql compatible server.